# How do I check for a file and then move to hdfs?

Tags: python, hdfs

I'm getting a file at a location "/tmp". Another process will place files to the temp location. I don't know the name of the file. I need to write a script to check if a file exists. If it does, then move it to an HDFS location, otherwise exit.

I guess question 1 is: Are there wild characters in Python? If so, I can just do

os.path.isfile("/tmp/mike/*")

But I realized * doesn't work.

Or if I have keywords. How do I search by keywords?

Thanks.

Comment: file_exist = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.__contains__(s)] is another way, u can tweak it to your need- This if you for any reason want an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be an easier way.

If you want to search by keyword in the file name.

```
tRoot = "__path to temp dir"
keyword = "You keyword here"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(tRoot):
    for file in files:
        if keyword in file:
            fullPath = str(os.path.join(root, file))
            #file is the filename
```

If you want to search by extension.

```
tRoot = "__path to temp dir"
extension = "You extension here"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(tRoot):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(extension):
            fullPath = str(os.path.join(root, file))
            #file is the filename
```

Comment: Should I do anything before running this script? I added import os.path
from os import path at the top but an error occurred: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'

Comment: I'm sorry. I corrected my code. It was supposed to be if keyword in file and not if file.contains(keyword)

Comment: What's the usage of for root, dirs, files?

Comment: The above code finds all files in the current directory (example: temp/youFileWithKeyWord.ext) and it’s subdirectories (ex: temp/folder2/yourFileWithKeyWord.ext). This might help you: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If the keyword is found, and I want to move to HDFS location. Do you have any suggestions? I'm doing subprocess.call(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-copyFromLocal','/tmp/mike/test*','hdfs:///user/app'], shell=True) but it's throwing an error.

Comment: I’m sorry Cha but I’m not familiar with that process. Try asking another question with your objective, code and error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199266/discussion-between-harsha-and-hua-cha).